# Please fix the error in simple Java code

Tags: java, inheritance

I am trying extend the Class Test1 using Class E and I just want to display a message.

```
class Test1
{
 public static void main(String[] args) 
 {
    E e = new E();
 } 
} 
class E extends Test1
{
  System.out.println("Hello World!");
}
```

I get these errors:

```
Test1.java:10: <identifier> expected
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
                          ^
Test1.java:10: illegal start of type
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
                           ^
2 errors
```

Comment: Do you know what that error means? What effort you put to solve this problem?

Comment: class E extends Test1
{ public E(){
  System.out.println("Hello World!");}
}

Comment: @PeterRader No. His output is not in a method/constructor

Comment: You can't have code just laying around in a class. It has to be inside a block.

Comment: I suggest you read some resources on how classes in Java work. This is not what they should be used for.

Comment: no. bcz i am unable to find cause according to error. Now i am understand. thx..

Answer (score 2):

Your E class is missing the constructor.

```
class Test1
{
 public static void main(String[] args) 
 {
    E e = new E();
 } 
} 
class E extends Test1
{
  public E(){
     System.out.println("Hello World!");
  }
}
```

**OR**
Class E should have instance block

```
class Test1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        E e = new E();
    } 
} 
class E extends Test1 {
  {
     System.out.println("Hello World!");
  }
}
```

Comment: It's actually only missing a pair of braces.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik As Marko said, just a pair of braces is needed. The default constructor is added by the compiler

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik That would have the side effect of adding the code to every constructor in the class. That will probably be unexpected if they add more custructors.

Comment: True, @MarkoTopolnik is right, constructor was added just for clarity

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Sure, and the *only* person who browses answers is the OP.

Comment: If you're concerned about the broader public, then please write an answer which starts by explaining the basics of OOP and why the code posted is nonsense with or without the braces.